# PHP Loops to Functions

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I understand looping through MySQL tables with `for` loops and extracting out data via `if` statements (among other things).

But now I am trying to better understand functions. So to keep it simple and a point of reference I understand, this is what I am used to doing:

```
require 'get_member_email.php'//where $memberEmail is defined
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOMETHING='SOMETHING ELSE'";
$results = mysql_query($query);

foreach ($results as $data){
      if ($memberEmail == $data['member_email']{ 
             $id = $data['member_id'];
      }
}
```

I would normally store that script in a file then call into my website with a `require` (as well as the file 'above' it (where $memberEmail is defined), then call both files into my webpage via:

```
require 'get_member_email.php';// where $member email is defined
require 'get_memeber_id.php'; //where the code above is 
echo "<h1>Your member ID is: $id</h1>";
```

1) How would I write this functions
2) Is there any benefit to doing so? (rather than just keeping my `require` and `for` loops)

Comment: Get all data out then using a loop get get required data is a bad idea. Add a where condition to the sql to get only what you want.

Comment: yes I know that, I'll add that so as not to distract... but that wasn't my question: @xdazz

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Okay your question is how to write a function.

```
function loopFunction() {
    require 'get_member_email.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOMETHING='SOMETHING ELSE'";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    foreach ($results as $data) {
        if ($memberEmail == $data['member_email']{ 
         $id = $data['member_id'];
        }
    }
}
```

by doing this you can store this process and simply call it by

```
loopFunction();
```

2) Yes there is a benefit of doing this. since you already define this as a function you dont have to create this process again. you can just call it.

This benefits you when this process needs to be repeated or re used in other cases.

Comment: Yea that make sense... isn't there return statement missing though? how would I get the data out?

Comment: if you want to return the data simply add a return $id; at the bottom of your foreach

Answer (score 1):

You grab all of the data of a single member in your database call already.

```
require 'get_member_email.php'; // Define $memberEmail

// Select the member's data from the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE member_email = '".$memberEmail."'";

// Only need one member's data, so grab it.
$results = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$id = $results['id'];
```

Note: `mysql` queries are depreciated in newer versions of PHP; use [mysqli calls](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: That isn't what I was asking at all. I already know how to do all that. I could write a whole "functioning' php-based web-app without ever calling a function and I am trying to change that.